# Can't draw Google Maps v2 with Navigation Drawer

Tags: android, google-maps, android-studio, navigation-drawer, android-maps-v2

Ok, so I just begun with Android Development and basically my issue is what title describes. What I tried until now is to create a default Drawer Navigation Activity project and write a Google Maps Fragment class and lastly inflate this to the main content.

The reason I want this to work is because Drawer Nav Activity looks nice and it would be nice to have google maps in the main screen of it.

By reading the Docs: http://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html I understand that in order to successfully display a fragment inside another activity you need to firstly create a Google Maps Class that extends MapFragment or Fragment and secondly declare the fragment inside the activity's layout file.

No matter what I tried, it just never works. I have managed to draw Google Maps successfully but its Class code is not being invoked, thus Maps actions do not exist.

The google maps responsible GMapsFragment Class (I think that the marked line below (35) is causing the error in conjuction with the maps xml file):

```
package com.example.s0me0n3.ytgooglemapstut;

import android.app.Fragment;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;

import com.google.android.gms.maps.CameraUpdateFactory;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.MapView;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.MarkerOptions;


public class GMapsFragment extends Fragment {

    public MapView mapView;
    private static GoogleMap googleMap;


    public GMapsFragment() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        Log.w("GMAPS", "Map place 1");
        // **********************************************************************************
        // The line below throws an inflation error when trying to parse the fragment_map xml
        // **********************************************************************************
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_map, container, false);
        // Log.w("GMAPS", "Map place 1");

        if (googleMap != null)
            setUpMap();
        if (googleMap == null) {
            googleMap = ((MapFragment) MyActivity.fragmentManager.findFragmentById(R.id.ContactMapView)).getMap();
            if (googleMap != null) {
                setUpMap();
            }
        }

        return rootView;
    }

    private static void setUpMap() {
        googleMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
        googleMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(new LatLng(41.009471, 28.916134)).title("baslik"));
        googleMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(new LatLng(41.009471, 28.916134), 12.0f));
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroyView() {
        super.onDestroyView();
        if (googleMap != null) {
            MyActivity.fragmentManager.beginTransaction()
                    .remove(MyActivity.fragmentManager.findFragmentById(R.id.ContactMapView))
                    .commit();
            googleMap = null;
        }
    }
}
```

and the main activity class MyActivity:

```
package com.example.s0me0n3.ytgooglemapstut;

import android.app.Activity;

import android.app.ActionBar;
import android.app.Fragment;
import android.app.FragmentManager;
import android.app.FragmentTransaction;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.os.Build;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.preference.PreferenceManager;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Gravity;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.CheckBox;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment;


public class MyActivity extends Activity
        implements NavigationDrawerFragment.NavigationDrawerCallbacks {


    public static FragmentManager fragmentManager;
    /**
     * Fragment managing the behaviors, interactions and presentation of the navigation drawer.
     */
    private NavigationDrawerFragment mNavigationDrawerFragment;


    /**
     * Used to store the last screen title. For use in {@link #restoreActionBar()}.
     */
    private CharSequence mTitle;

    // private GMapsFragment _gmaps;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_my);

        mNavigationDrawerFragment = (NavigationDrawerFragment)
                getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.navigation_drawer);
        mTitle = getTitle();

        // _gmaps = (GMapsFragment)
        //        getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.ContactMapView);

        // FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = _gmaps.beginTransaction();


        // Set up the drawer.
        mNavigationDrawerFragment.setUp(
                R.id.navigation_drawer,
                (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout));

        FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
        FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
        // *** The Note below is pointing here! ***
        GMapsFragment fragment = new GMapsFragment();
        fragmentTransaction.add(R.id.container, fragment);
        fragmentTransaction.commit();

    }

    @Override
    public void onNavigationDrawerItemSelected(int position) {
        // update the main content by replacing fragments
        FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
        fragmentManager.beginTransaction()
                .replace(R.id.container, PlaceholderFragment.newInstance(position + 1))
                .commit();
    }

    public void onSectionAttached(int number) {
        switch (number) {
            case 1:
                mTitle = getString(R.string.title_section1);
                break;
            case 2:
                mTitle = getString(R.string.title_section2);
                break;
            case 3:
                mTitle = getString(R.string.title_section3);
                break;
        }
    }

    public void restoreActionBar() {
        ActionBar actionBar = getActionBar();
        actionBar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_STANDARD);
        actionBar.setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(true);
        actionBar.setTitle(mTitle);
    }


    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        if (!mNavigationDrawerFragment.isDrawerOpen()) {
            // Only show items in the action bar relevant to this screen
            // if the drawer is not showing. Otherwise, let the drawer
            // decide what to show in the action bar.
            getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.my, menu);
            restoreActionBar();
            return true;
        }
        return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            // showMsg("Settings reeee");
            // Log.w("MyActivity", "Will now log u out...");
            Intent intent = new Intent();
            intent.setClass(MyActivity.this, SetPreferenceActivity.class);
            startActivityForResult(intent, 0);
            // return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    private void showMsg(String msg) {
        Toast toast = Toast.makeText(this, msg, Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
        toast.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER, toast.getXOffset() / 2, toast.getYOffset() / 2);
        toast.show();
    }

    /**
     * A placeholder fragment containing a simple view.
     */
    public static class PlaceholderFragment extends Fragment {
        /**
         * The fragment argument representing the section number for this
         * fragment.
         */
        private static final String ARG_SECTION_NUMBER = "section_number";

        /**
         * Returns a new instance of this fragment for the given section
         * number.
         */
        public static PlaceholderFragment newInstance(int sectionNumber) {
            PlaceholderFragment fragment = new PlaceholderFragment();
            Bundle args = new Bundle();
            args.putInt(ARG_SECTION_NUMBER, sectionNumber);
            fragment.setArguments(args);
            return fragment;
        }

        public PlaceholderFragment() {
        }

        @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_my, container, false);
            return rootView;
        }

        @Override
        public void onAttach(Activity activity) {
            super.onAttach(activity);
            ((MyActivity) activity).onSectionAttached(
                    getArguments().getInt(ARG_SECTION_NUMBER));
        }
    }

}
```

*Note*: If I change the line 73 "GMapsFragment fragment = new GMapsFragment();" in the MyActivity Class with something like this "Fragment fragment = new MapFragment();" then it works fine, but of course the GMapsFragment is not being run. Instead a default gmaps is being displayed with no functionalities at all. However, I do not understand why the inflation of my own gmaps fragment will not work.

After that, I understand that I have to include the Google Maps fragment inside the main xml.. so here is the activity_my.xml:

```
<!-- A DrawerLayout is intended to be used as the top-level content view using match_parent for both width and height to consume the full space available. -->
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MyActivity">

    <!-- As the main content view, the view below consumes the entire
         space available using match_parent in both dimensions. -->
    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

    <!-- android:layout_gravity="start" tells DrawerLayout to treat
         this as a sliding drawer on the left side for left-to-right
         languages and on the right side for right-to-left languages.
         If you're not building against API 17 or higher, use
         android:layout_gravity="left" instead. -->
    <!-- The drawer is given a fixed width in dp and extends the full height of
         the container. -->

    <fragment android:id="@+id/navigation_drawer"
        android:layout_width="@dimen/navigation_drawer_width"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:name="com.example.s0me0n3.ytgooglemapstut.NavigationDrawerFragment"
        tools:layout="@layout/fragment_navigation_drawer" />

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

and the fragment_map.xml:

```
<fragment xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:map="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/ContactMapView"
    android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
 />
```

Here is my AndroidManifest.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.s0me0n3.ytgooglemapstut" >

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>

    <permission android:name="com.example.s0me0n3.ytgooglemapstut.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE" android:protectionLevel="signature" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.example.s0me0n3.ytgooglemapstut.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.example.s0me0n3.ytgooglemapstut.permission.READ_GSERVICES" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
    <uses-feature android:glEsVersion="0x00020000" android:required="true"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="com.example.s0me0n3.ytgooglemapstut.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.example.s0me0n3.ytgooglemapstut.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.version" android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
        <activity
            android:name=".MyActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>



        <activity
            android:name=".SetPreferenceActivity"
            android:label="User Settings" >
        </activity>

        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
            android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
            android:value="AIzaSyCoyacHtM9Nl0rjDYFJqV9wUQfiN6OlDOU"/>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

The Logcat errors that I am receiving after running the app is:

```
10-10 12:44:55.420    8017-8017/com.example.s0me0n3.ytgooglemapstut E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.s0me0n3.ytgooglemapstut, PID: 8017
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.s0me0n3.ytgooglemapstut/com.example.s0me0n3.ytgooglemapstut.MyActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #1: Error inflating class fragment
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2195)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2245)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:135)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1196)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
     Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #1: Error inflating class fragment
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:714)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:469)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:397)
            at com.example.s0me0n3.ytgooglemapstut.GMapsFragment.onCreateView(GMapsFragment.java:35)
            at android.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:1700)
            at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:890)
            at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1040)
            at android.app.Activity.onCreateView(Activity.java:4805)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:690)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:469)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:397)
            at com.example.s0me0n3.ytgooglemapstut.GMapsFragment.onCreateView(GMapsFragment.java:35)
            at android.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:1700)
            at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:890)
            at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1062)
            at android.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:684)
            at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1447)
            at android.app.Activity.performStart(Activity.java:5240)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2168)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2245)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:135)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1196)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
     Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Binary XML file line #1: Duplicate id 0x7f050017, tag null, or parent id 0x7f050015 with another fragment for com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment
            at android.app.Activity.onCreateView(Activity.java:4791)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:690)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:469)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:397)
            at com.example.s0me0n3.ytgooglemapstut.GMapsFragment.onCreateView(GMapsFragment.java:35)
            at android.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:1700)
            at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:890)
            at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1040)
            at android.app.Activity.onCreateView(Activity.java:4805)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:690)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:469)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:397)
            at com.example.s0me0n3.ytgooglemapstut.GMapsFragment.onCreateView(GMapsFragment.java:35)
            at android.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:1700)
            at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:890)
            at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1062)
            at android.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:684)
            at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1447)
            at android.app.Activity.performStart(Activity.java:5240)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2168)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2245)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:135)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1196)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Last words.. I tried running the GMapsFragment class from other xml files or the my_activity.xml but I always end up getting errors.

So, after that wall spam, let me explain to you my goal. I would like to use the default produced Drawer Nav code from Android Studio in conjuction with a Google Maps that is being displayed on the main content.

Any enlightenment would be awesome. I have been searching for the last 6 days for a solution with no luck. It has to be a really silly mistake, I know but I am stuck.

P.S: I have seen examples using the SupportMapFragment but I would like to make my above code work or understand why this is impossible if so.

Answer (score 0):

Change your fragment_map.xml to :

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" 
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/ContactMapView"
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
    />

</RelativeLayout>
```